# Finding a point through which two circles pass

Tags: geometry, circles

Assume two points $A(x_1, y_1)$ and $B(P,Q)$ such that radius of a circle passing through two points is $R_1$. Now assume another point $C(x_2, y_2)$ such that radius of circle passing through $B$ and $C$ is $R_2$.

If values of variables except $P,Q$  is given is it possible to find the values of $P,Q$? if yes can you please explain how to do that

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @infinitylord Why should that be a condition?

Comment: @RamanujanXV Nothing, Actually I am studying Petroleum Engineering, in that subject we have a one huge question on designing a wellbore, above question was small calculation in that questions (I was trying out different method) where I got stuck.  Last time I studied geometry was in 12th std, so I have absolutely no idea weather it is possible to do this, thats why I asked this question

Comment: @infinitylord no thats not a condition. does it mean it is impossible to solve this question

Comment: @Nivekithan If all you know is that $AB \le 2R_1$ and $BC \le 2R_2$ then that's not enough information to determine $B$ in general.

Comment: Did you try to draw it? You have two solutions - just draw circles through A and C.

Comment: @Moti "*You have two solutions*" $\;-\;$ I don't see how that follows. Instead, you have $0$, $1$ or infinitely many solutions depending on whether $AC \gt$, or $=$, or $\lt 2R_1+2R_2$.

Comment: Infinity (when Two circles identical), 0 (if they do not intersect), 1 (if they tangent) and 2 (if intersect) - you get the equations of the circles by calculating the center of each circle based on Perpendicular Bisector and intersecting a circle around the point with the given Radius.

Comment: @Moti Point $\,B\,$ is not known, that's precisely what the question is supposed to find. So you cannot draw the perpendicular bisectors, and you cannot construct either circle because, again, you don't know $\,B\,$.

Comment: You are all right. You draw a circle 2R1 with A center and a circle 2R2 with C center. B is any point of the overlap of these two circles. I assume this what @dxiv mean.

Comment: @Moti The OP wrote that the circle of radius $R_1$ passes through $A$ and $B$, so $A$ is a point on that circle, not its center. Same goes for the circle "*through $B$ and $C$*".

Comment: Exactly - so B can be at most 2R1 from A.